erro fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'pcesar@fedora.(none)')
Bom dia.
Estou tentando realizar um commit no git utilizando o fedora, porém esta me retornando o erro abaixo:
Author identity unknown
*** Please tell me who you are.
Run
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'usuario@fedora.(none)')
Utilizando git config --list --global | grep user vi q minhas configurações estão certas
user.mail=meuemail@gmail.com
user.name=meusuario
ALguem pode me dar uma ajuda?
Bom dia.
Estou tentando realizar um commit no git utilizando o fedora, porém esta me retornando o erro abaixo:
Author identity unknown
*** Please tell me who you are.
Run
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'usuario@fedora.(none)')
Utilizando git config --list --global | grep user vi q minhas configurações estão certas
user.mail=meuemail@gmail.com
user.name=meusuario
ALguem

https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions

I've already done this process. But it's not working.

Please click on the Edit button underneath your question, translate it into English, and save it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
